# ¿Cómo puedo hacer ésta animación de carga en C++?

Tags: c++, dev-c++

¿Cómo puedo hacer esta animación de carga en la que la barra está girando, pero en C++? (El código del vídeo está en Python)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mmm, bueno es un poco cliché, pero sería algo así:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>

void gotoxy(short x, short y)
{
    COORD pos = { x, y };
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), pos);
}

int main()
{
    for (int cont2 = 1; cont2 <= 5; cont2++)
    {
        for (int cont = 0;cont<4;cont++)
        {
            gotoxy(0, 0);
            if (cont == 0)
                std::cout << "\304";
            if (cont == 1)
                std::cout << "\134";
            if (cont == 2)
                std::cout << "\174";
            if (cont == 3)
                std::cout << "\57";
            Sleep(200);
        }
    }
    std::cout<<std::endl;
    system("pause");
}
```

Esta **no** es la mejor forma de hacerlo pero es lo más rápido que pude, **si quieres cambiar la posición de donde aparece, cambia el** `gotoxy(0,0);` **por unas variables, u otra posición de pantalla**, ejemplo:
`gotoxy(x,y);`
`gotoxy(5,24);`